# Browsing through file system in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which user can select folders. The folders can be in external memory or removable storage. So I need to display root folders of external memory and removable storage of the device. I tried

```
context.dataDir
context.filesDir
context.externalCacheDir
context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

but all of them point to external/internal storage specific to myapp not device ex: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files
So I am stuck with how to show root locations of file system in android?

**Note**: The other related questions in stackoverflow have answers that use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which is depricated and android docs suggests to use MediaStore but it is not clear how to browse through file system with it

Comment: That deprecated function gives you the root you are after so use it. It just gives you `/storage/emulated/0` which is the same as the start of `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files`. You could conclude that you dont need the deprecated one as all was already in the other.

Comment: The user can select any folder if you just start an intent for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Have a look at `context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` if you need removable storage.

Answer (score 0):

Android has updated its policy for shared storage which allows apps to request files based on their type/visibility rather than their location in the file system. So to build apps that requires traditional file system browsing capabilities we need to request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and use `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` intent action to direct users to a system settings page where they can enable **Allow access to manage all files**. This is allowed only to apps with the following use cases

- File managers
- Backup and restore
- Anti-virus apps
- Document management apps

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play